# Using ftl display list from POST method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker, cuba-platform

Sorry for my english! 
I am new to Spring and FTL. 
I want to display `firstName` and `lastName` using `<#list` template, but I could not recognize any sequences in my POST method, could some one please explain to me. Again I am a newbie and please don't judge me if I don't understand what I should. I am using CUBA STUDIO 6.8 and IDEA. Also I'm working on this task in portal module

This is how I add `firstName` and `lastName` to database using my ftl form and Portal Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/add")
public String add(Model model){
    PersonPojo personPojo = new PersonPojo();
    model.addAttribute("personPojo", personPojo);
    return "add";
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public String save(Model model, @ModelAttribute("personPojo") PersonPojo personPojo){

    String firstName = personPojo.getFirstName();
    String lastName = personPojo.getLastName();
    PersonPojo newPerson = new PersonPojo(firstName, lastName);

    Person standardEntity = metadata.create(Person.class);
    standardEntity.setFirtName(newPerson.getFirstName());
    standardEntity.setLastName(newPerson.getLastName());
    dataManager.commit(standardEntity);

    return "redirect:/allPersons";
}
```

**My ftl form:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="person">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"> <br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"> <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form></body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: take a look here https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html

Comment: could you add an example json?

Comment: @Fjordo i dont use json, just springmvc, ftl, cuba's entities, pojos

Comment: @Fjordo I've looked to this docs and as I mentioned above I could not recognize sequence for #list  in my spring POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, If someone is interested i will post my solution here:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/allPersons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersons(Model model) {
            LoadContext loadJohn = new LoadContext(John.class);
            loadJohn.setQueryString("select u from test6$John u");
            model.addAttribute("users", dataService.loadList(loadJohn));
            return "list";
    }
```

And the ftl should look like this: 
The problem i faced next was I did not know I have to check list for null. **!""** does that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Person List</h3>
<a href="/app-portal/add">Add Person</a>
<br><br>
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <#list users as show>
            <tr>
                <td>${show.firstName!""}</td>
                <td>${show.lastName!""}</td>
            </tr>
        </#list>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help to people like me. 
Also, If someone knows how to delete and update data please share.
Thanks!